# Как преобразовать unicode-строку в кирилицу?

Tags: c#

Извиняюсь за тупые вопросы. Но я ни черта не понимаю в кодировках. 
Есть вот такая строка: \u041f\u0440\u043e\u0434\u0443\u043a\u0442 \u0434\u043e\u0431\u0430\u0432\u043b\u0435\u043d

Как ее преобразовать в нормальную кириллицу?

Пробовал пример с [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.text.encoding.aspx#Y11970) - не помогает. Строка вообще не изменяется.

Comment: Эта строка уже содержит кириллицу. https://ideone.com/CuNAun

Comment: Ну или если ваша строка реально содержит не один символ `'\u041f'`, а 6 символов `'\\'`, `'u'`, `'0'`, `'4'`, `'1'`, `'f'`, то вы, вангую, вместо использования JSON-парсера выдираете текст из JSON-ответа регулярками. Просто не делайте этого.

Comment: Думал есть решение. Но ладно... буду юзать newtonsoft.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нашлось неожиданно простое решение:

```
var s = @"\u041f\u0440\u043e\u0434\u0443\u043a\u0442 " +
        @"\u0434\u043e\u0431\u0430\u0432\u043b\u0435\u043d";
var d = Regex.Unescape(s); // "Продукт добавлен"
```

---

Корень проблемы в том, что у вас не Unicode-строка, а строка, в которой не-ASCII-символы закодированы escape-последовательностями. То есть проблема не в кодировках, а в содержимом самой строки.

Скорее всего, вы получили такую строку при попытке ручного разбора какого-то высокоуровневого формата (JSON?). Лучше всего в таких случаях не изобретать велосипед, а довериться готовому парсеру.

Comment: Обычно юзаю готовые парсеры, Но тут всего одна такая операция. тянуть всю либу не резонно.